# Why this counting sort return input instead of sorted table?

Tags: c, counting-sort

I'm writing counting sort in C. N is the number of elements in table which is to be sorted, k is max value that any of this element can be. However, this code, leaves me with the same table as the input. What's wrong?

```c
void countingSort(int *tab, int n, int k) {
    int *counters = (int *)malloc(k * sizeof(int));
    int *result = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        counters[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        counters[tab[i]]++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        int tmp = counters[i];
        while (tmp--) {
            result[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    tab = result;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more descriptive of a problem or question than *What is wrong with my code?*. It's also not necessary to repeat repat repeat the information you've already provided in tags; the [tag:counting-sort] tag is enough to tell people your post is about counting sort, so you don't need to repeat it mutiple times in the title. If your title clearly explains a problem or asks a question, it helps you get an answer more quickly, and it's more useful to future readers who are scanning a list of search results trying to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- `int *result = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));` uses an incorrect size. The array element type is `int`, not `int*`. You should write:

  ```
  int *result = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  ```

  or better:

  ```
  int *result = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(*result));
  ```

  note also that the cast is useless in C, unlike C++ where it is mandatory:

  ```
  int *result = malloc(n * sizeof(*result));
  ```
- you could avoid the extra initializing loop by using `calloc()`:

  ```
  int *counters = calloc(n, sizeof(*counters));
  ```
- a major problem: the result array is never returned to the caller: `tab = result;` just modifies the argument value, not the caller's variable.  You should instead use the `tab` array to store the results directly.
- you do not free the arrays, causing memory leaks.
- you do not test for allocation success, causing undefined behavior if memory is not available.  You should return an error status indicating this potential problem.

Here is a corrected version:

```
// assuming all entries in tab are > 0 and < k
int countingSort(int *tab, int n, int k) {
    int *counters = calloc(k, sizeof(*counters));
    if (counters == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        counters[tab[i]]++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        int tmp = counters[i];
        while (tmp--) {
            tab[j++] = i;
        }
    }
    free(counters);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You pass tab to the function by pointer. However you need to change not the value, but address of the variable. So you should pass address of the pointer to countingSort.

```
void countingSort(int **tab, int n, int k)
```